# Hierarchical Model with RV in Bounds

Tags: statistics

Assume you have a probability distribution defined as:

\begin{equation}
p(x; \alpha) = \frac{1}{2 \ln(\alpha)} \frac{1}{x} I_{\left[\frac{1}{\alpha},\alpha\right]}(x)
\end{equation}

where $\alpha > 0$ and $I(x)$ represents the indicator function or the domain over which the probability distribution is defined. This probability distribution has no significance to me other than the parameter $\alpha$ is also contained in the bounds of the distribution.

Now assume we have a hierarchical distribution as follows:

\begin{align}
X &\overset{iid}{\sim} p(\alpha)\\
\alpha &\overset{iid}{\sim} p(\beta)
\end{align}

Solving this provides you:

\begin{equation}
p(X=x) = \int_{\frac{1}{\beta}}^\beta \frac{1}{2 \ln(\alpha)} \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{2 \ln(\beta)} \frac{1}{\alpha} d\alpha = \frac{-\ln(-\ln(\beta)) + \ln(\ln(\beta))}{4 x \ln(\beta)} I_{\left[\frac{1}{\beta},\beta\right]}(x)
\end{equation}

Now here is the confusing thing and this is also how I am pretty sure I am missing something critical with the bounds. This distribution is *complex*. No value of $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ is possible.

Since this is a seemingly simple hierarchical model, I am assuming there is some issue with the bounds that I am not familiar with. Back in my day in mathematical statistics, I don't ever recall handling distributions that had the hierarchical parameter also in the bounds.

So any insight the community could provide would be of great value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that if you define $p(x;\alpha)$ in the way that you have, the restriction is not $\alpha > 0$, but rather, $\alpha > 1$; this is because $$0 < \frac{1}{\alpha} < \alpha \iff \alpha > 1,$$ and of course, $\log \alpha < 0$ if $\alpha < 1$. Consequently, if $\alpha \sim p(\beta)$, we run into the problem of dealing with the case where realizations of $\alpha$ are less than $1$; i.e., $$\Pr[\alpha < 1 \mid \beta] = \int_{a = 1/\beta}^1 p(a;\beta) \, da,$$ which is positive if $\beta > 1$.

We can fix this problem by defining an alternative density parametrized as follows:  $$f_X(x \mid \gamma) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2\log \gamma} \frac{1}{x} \mathbb 1(1/\gamma \le x \le \gamma), & \gamma \ge 1 \\
\frac{1}{-2 \log \gamma} \frac{1}{x} \mathbb 1(\gamma \le x \le 1/\gamma), & \gamma < 1. \end{cases}$$  This of course is equivalent to writing $$f_X(x \mid \gamma) = p(x;\max(\gamma,1/\gamma)).$$